# "Араб" і "арап" — абсолютні синоніми?

Tags: синоніми

Цікавить питання чи застаріле слово **АРАП** це абсолютний синонім до слова **АРАБ**? У [літературному слововживанні](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53392/30032.html) знаходжу:

> **АРАБ – АРАП**
>
> **Араб**, -а, мн. -и, -ів. Представник великої групи народів, які населяють арабські країни Північно-Західної Азії та Північної Африки. Ладан горить на жертовнику, смоли горять запахущі, Що з полудневих країн нам посилає араб (М.Зеров).
>
> **Арап**, -а, мн. -и, -ів, заст. Чорношкіра людина, негр. – От чорні люде так дійсно є. Я сам на свої очі бачив в Одесі: арапами звуться (І. Нечуй-Левицький).

Чи можна в історичних статтях вживати ці слова як синоніми?

Comment: Я перепрошую, звісно, але що вас наштовхнуло на думку, що це синоніми? Ви справді вважаєте, що араби чорношкірі?

Comment: Наштовхнула на думку, інформація на російськомовному сайті:http://mysynonyms.ru/a-letter/arap-4221

Comment: 50% тексту на сторінці написано щоб "заманювати" до себе користувачів пошукових систем (великий об'єм тексту де повторюються одні й ті самі ключові слова). Я не думаю що такі сайти варті довіри.

Comment: @Artemix я взагалі не думаю, що щось російськомовне (окрім хіба dic.academic.ru/) варто довіри. Більше часу піде на перевірку інформації.

Comment: @Iva_ukr є купа українських словників синонімів, від goroh.in.ua через ukrainskamova.com до http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/ (треба натиснути синонімія), не варто ходити по всіляких незрозумілих російськомовних джерелах, вони відомі своїм нехлюйським ставленням до української мови.

Comment: @P. Vovk дякую, візьму на замітку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Чи застарїле?

Відносно поважний словник [в 20 книгах](//sum20ua.com/entry/search/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF) зазначає *арап* як *застарїле* ще з [в 11 книгах](http://sum.in.ua/s/arap). Тому можна вважати, же **так**.

## Цїлковиті сутямки?

В згаданих словниках всюди для *арап* є *негр*, котре в свою чергу [в 20 книгах](//sum20ua.com/entry/search/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8):

> Люди, що належать до негроїдної раси

Щось подібне і [в 11 книгах](http://sum.in.ua/s/neghry), просто описані ще додаткові гісторичні рїчи:

> Назва корінного населення [тропічної Африки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8), яке має темний колір шкіри і *належить до негроїдної раси*, а також нащадків африканців-негроїдів, примусово переселених у 16‑19 ст. в Америку.

При цьому *араб* [в 20 книгах](//sum20ua.com/entry/search/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8): *група народів, що становить основне населення Південно-Західної Азії* (в 11: *Передньої Азії*) *та Північної Африки*.

За місцем проживання розбіжности, тому вважатимо, що **нї**.

## Сутямки в літописах?

Для початку [розглянемо](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF) старїші словники.

Лиш *Грінченко* 1909 року вказує одразу очевидні сутямки для *арап*:

> 1. Аравитянинъ, арабъ. *Желех.*
> 2. Негръ.
> 3. Человѣкъ со смуглымъ цвѣтомъ лица.
> 4. Грязный, запачканный человѣкъ.

Инші словники переважно вказують слова *мурин*. З словника *Уманця і Спілки* 1893‑1898 років ясно, що він не білий. В тому ж словнику зрозуміло, що:

> *Ара́пъ* = ара́п, му́рин. — Мурин нїколи не буде білим. *н. пр.*
>
> *Негръ, негритя́нка* = му́рин (С. З.), му́ринка. — Як мурин білим, так дурень розумним нїколи не буде. н. пр.

[Знача частина словників](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD), як і новіший в [11 книгах](http://sum.in.ua/s/muryn) зазначють *мурин* як *негр*. Також видно, же ще втодї, наприклад за Кримським, слово *мурин* почато старїти і ставати *негром*. Однак той же Кримський з Єфремовом зазначають в иншому дописі:

> *Мавр, Маврита́нин, -рита́нка* – мавр, маврі́йка, маврета́нець (‑нця), маврета́нка, мавретя́нин, мавретя́нка, (*чёрный*) му́рин, му́ринка.

Тобто, схоже, що *мурин*, котрий *арап* — є чорним *мавром*. Вагу додають инша значна частина словників, котрі вказують *мурин* як *мавр*.

[Сучасний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=49053&page=1543) і [відносно сучасний](http://sum.in.ua/s/mavry) словники в книгах вказають *мавр* як: *у період античності та в середні віки — европейська назва корінного населення Північної Африки (крім Єгипту), а пізнїше арабів, які у 8 ст. підкорили Північну Африку та Піренейський півострів.* Як видно, дещо збігається з означенням *араб*: частково проживанням, а згодом прямо вказують.

Нагадаю ланцюґ: *арап* → *негр* / *мурин* → *мавр* → *араб*.

За [словопоходженєвим](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF) словником слова є з [одного](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=81) першоджерела: турецьке *arap* «араб; нерг» → арабське  *‘árab* «араб». Схоже, завдяки турецькій маємо такі ускладнення. Доволї цїкаво, що наше *араб* мало инший шлях: французьке *arabe* → латинське *arabus* → арабська. На цьому можна не зупинятися: *Аравія* → старословʼянська → грецьке *Ἀραβία*. Тут *арап* = *араб*, але через ріжні шляхи та барви, то вони ***частково* сутямки, але з увагою на час, місце й, очевидно, зьміст**.